# Return text surrounded by double tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I am looping through list with urls. On each page there is between 1 and n descriptions which are surrounded by double p tag.

```
BeautifulSoup.find(class_='view-content')

# url 1
<div class="view-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="description">
<p><p>One animal</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

# url 2
<div class="view-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="description">
<p><p>One person</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="description">
<p><p>Two people </p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I use

```
for d in soup.find(class_='view-content').find_all('p'):
    dd = d.contents[0]
    print(dd)
```

I get

```
<p>One animal</p>One animal
<p>One person</p>One person
<p>Two people</p>Two people
```

Instead of expected

```
One animal
One person
Two people
```

Any way to retrieve content surrounded by double p tags?

Edit: The following returns the same, but at least without p tags.

```
for d in soup.find_all("div",class_="view-content"):
    print(' '.join(i.text for i in review.find_all('p')[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
# url 1
<div class="view-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="description">
<p><p>One animal</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

# url 2
<div class="view-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="description">
<p><p>One person</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="description">
<p><p>Two people </p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
divs = doc.selects('div.view-content')
datas=[]
for div in divs:
  datas.extend ([p.text for p in div.ps])
print (datas)
```

Result:

```
['One animal', 'One person', 'Two people']
```